# Get latest iOS on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

Yup!

I was checking inside the Xcode OS list to download the latest iOS (14.X) but there's only 'til iOS 12.4.
I've checked if there's new updated for simulator but nothing found.

I'm using a macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and running the Xcode 11.1 version.

Any idea where can I get the latest versions? Need it to check iPad 8th generation in a project :(

Many thanks!

Comment: I believe that the latest version of Xcode is 12.1, not 11.1

Comment: @gmdev omg u're right... it doesn't let me update it if I don't update the operating system before

Comment: Yes, you will have to update the operating system before you are able to update Xcode.

Comment: @gmdev Can't do it... not enough space xd deleted everything that was unnecessary and still not enough space. My disk is only 100GB of space and only 22GB are occupied by apps (necessary for working)